# Showing that the general linear group is isomorphic to symmetric group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, linear-groups

Let $G = GL(2, \Bbb Z_2)$, the general linear group of $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices with coefficients in $\Bbb Z_2$. Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

I'm having trouble getting started with this one. Both groups have six elements and I know I need to show that there is a bijection $f:G \to S_3$. I don't really know how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove that $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a non-abelian group of order 6? Any such group must be isomorphic to $S_3$, so you could appeal to that.

Comment: I could but is there a theorem that says non-abelian groups with the same order are isomorphic? @PrahladVaidyanathan

Comment: @Nid There are only two groups of order $6$: $\mathbb Z_6$ and $S_3$. So $S_3$ is the only nonabelian group of order six.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that they aren't isomorphic then? Because one is abelian iff the other is too.

Comment: Can you show that $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ is **non**abelian? @Nid

Comment: @JohnMa I can but I don't know how that would help.

Comment: So $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ is an nonabelian group of order $6$, so it is isomorphic to $S_3$, as suggested by Prahlad. @Nid

Answer (score 3):

The vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ has exactly three nonzero elements.  So, given some ordering of these,  there is a clear group homomorphism $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_2)\to S_3$.

Since the two groups have the same number of elements, it is enough to show that this map is injective.

Comment: But I still need to show that it is surjective. How do I do that?

Comment: @Nid Any injective function between two finite sets of the same size is surjective.

Comment: "They have the same number of elements": injectivity implies surjectivity.

Comment: So than that would imply bijection and it would thus be isomorphic?

Comment: @Nid A bijective homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of $GL(2,\mathbb F_2)$ can be viewed as a linear transformation $f$ on $\mathbb F_2^2$, which sends
$$(1,0)\mapsto x, (0,1)\mapsto y.$$

It follows that $f(1,1)=x+y$ is the only other non-zero vector. Thus $f$ defines a permutation $\sigma_f$ of the three non-zero vectors of $\mathbb F_2^2$.

The mapping
$$f\mapsto \sigma_f$$
is clearly a group homomorphism and invertible (take a permutation $\sigma$ on the three non-zero vectors and look at the images of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$).